# Prolema ao usar inputpicker no combo

Tags: jquery, filtro

Eu estou usando o inputpicker, um plugin do JQuery. Porém ele apresentou um problema com o filtro, ao filtrar as opções do combo e clicar em alguma ele ignora a nova ordem e pega o valor da opção que estava naquela posição antes do filtro.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

então quando eu clibo na opção 3 Net, ele exibea opção 1 jQuecry.

Esse erro também pode ser observado no link:
http://www.inputpicker.com/www/

Comment: Qual o código do plugin que está a utilizar ? Qual o exemplo que indica que não está a funcionar corretamente na página de documentação indicada ?

Comment: É o exemplo Filter input.

Não consigo postar o código completo do plugin, mas você pode fazer o download no link http://www.inputpicker.com/www/ . Na pasta src está o arquivo js.

Comment: Sim pelo que testei parece-me de facto que o plugin apresenta um erro quando se clica num elemento após haver uma filtragem pelo texto escrito. Sugiro [abrir um issue no Github](https://github.com/ukalpa/inputpicker/issues) para que o dono do plugin possa perceber que esse erro existe e corrigi-lo.